# Android OpenGl: When to start calling API functions?

Tags: android, api, opengl-es

I have noticed that if I try to call API calls before surface is created such as

GLES20.glGenTextures(textures.size(), textureHandle,0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[i]);

They don't behave properly, for example texture handler being returned as 0 all the time.

So I put my initiation methods under onSurfaceCreated call.

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1) {
    if(initiated)return;
    BitmapLoader.onOpenglGLInitiated();
    program.init();
    initiated = true;

}
```

However such results in being recalled whenever surface is recreated; when a user pauses and resumes as well.
In which reuslts in double initiation, thus an error.
I want to know where exactly should be a better place to put my initiation codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far what I´ve seen, it´s quite convenient to load textures in `onSurfaceCreated`

[Example 6: Texture (Nehe Lesson 6: Texture)](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html#zz-2.8)

Which errors do you exactly get?

Comment: It does not return me proper address. GLES20.glGenTextures(textures.size(), textureHandle,0); not returning proper handler.